# Codeigniter security concern - Sessions that last forever?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, session

I found something which I believe to be quite concerning while inspecting CodeIgniter's session handling mechanism.

```
$expire = $this->now - $this->sess_expiration;

$this->CI->db->where("last_activity < {$expire}");
$this->CI->db->delete($this->sess_table_name);
```

It appears that CI actually determines the session expiration time based on last_activity rather than a fixed, non-variable expiration field.

The problem here is that last_activity is updated to now() whenever the session is updated. So let's assume you are using CI defaults and have a session lasting 7200 seconds(2 hours) that's updated every 300 seconds(5 minutes)

The session is flagged as needing an update after 5 minutes of the last update, so if a user submits his session cookie after these 5 minutes, but before 2 hours, then CI will extend the session to last another 2 hours from this moment because last_activity will be updated to now().

This seems like a huge security risk to me, because as long as the user is active and keeps triggering the session update, its duration is extended indefinitely, effectively making the expiration setting useless. I've tested this by setting update to 10 seconds and expiration to 20. I can confirm that as long as I kept hitting refresh every 10 seconds, the session never expired!

Imagine if an attacker steals your login cookie and establishes a valid session. Even if you invalidate the login cookie, the attacker could keep his session valid indefinitely so long as he kept submitting the cookie often enough.

What do you think? Am I missing something important here? Or is this really as bad a security hole as it appears?

Comment: I think websites normally work like that. If you want a session to expire two hours after logging in, even if it has been in regular use during that session, then (a) that's an unusually high security requirement, and (b) you'll probably need your own session handler.

Comment: It's not a security hole. This is how PHP sessions work by default, looking at the modified time of session files before deciding whether to expire them or not.

Comment: Session timeout is used to expire _inactive_ sessions. You don't want you customers to have to log in again every two hours, as that is very annoying and potentially disruptive to whatever they were doing at your site at the moment their two-hours-since-login elapse.

Comment: Well, that would explain a few things. For some reason I never came across this information anywhere. Thank you all for the input.

Comment: Regarding the "if you invalidate a login cookie". After fetching the session (probably containing member_id), you could / should check if the user-credentials are still valid and destroy the session if not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get the point from the comments, but to simply post an answer, what you discovered is the proper function.

Sessions are ment to be 'extended' they are not created from initial fixed point in time, to + 7200 sec.  Its somewhat silly if you are someone working on something and suddenly while you are active, you get logged out.

As an alternative method, **if** you wanted to do what you describe, you would extend the `CI_Session` and modify that specific method, and save it as `MY_Session`.

See more details here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html